# QT process qmake cannot be executed error

Tags: qt, qmake

I am just a beginner at QT. I just wanted to make sure whether the compiler runs correctly or not but the in built compiler in qt doesn't seem to work. Whenever I try to build a program it says 'no suitable compiler detected try installing one or more compilers'. When I installed gcc compiler it detected it, but when I try to build that program again now it gives an error. It says 'process qmake cannot be executed'. If someone knows a solution to this it would be a great help.

Comment: Can you post exactly what command you're executing and what error message getting? Also run `whereis qmake` and `qmake -v`

Comment: 22:21:25: Running steps for project calqlatr...
22:21:25: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:21:25: Could not start process "mingw32-make.exe" 
Error while building/deploying project calqlatr (kit: clang)
When executing step "Make"
22:21:25: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Comment: this is what I get while I am trying to run a QT program

Comment: Looks like you are on Windows. I would suggest you installing Qt with the bundled Mingw (just chose this option at the Qt package manager). Long shot: have you checked you environment variables? Not sure if `qmake` requires than to include the compiler on Windows.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira..the QT mingw package is only available for 32 bit windows there is another package for 64 bit windows  it comes with a visual studio 2013...can I run 32 bit QT package on 64 bit windows??

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira I also tried adding QT to the environment variables but it made no difference it says 'there is no suitable compiler that can produce code for this QT version'...What should I do??

Comment: @ashim_code1 There are basically 3 compiler options on Windows: mingw-32, mingw-64 (or mingw-w64) and Visual Studio compiler. All of them works, but Visual Studio version is the best. Yes, you can run a 32 bit package on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: @ashim_code1 Have you tried compiling code from QtCreator? It may be easier to understand what's going on with its help. Just configure a compiler kit, and hit the "build" button. QtCreator is very powerful, and may show you some useful info to understand what's going on. Please, add some screenshots of your compiler kit configuration.

Comment: @ashim_code1 Ah! Please, add Mingw to your path too.